# Versions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I need to write Python compliant with 2.5.1. I currently have Python 3.1 on my machine. If I make a PyDev project and set the grammar to "2.5", will the code I write be compatible (both syntactically and semantically)? Or must I go download an older version of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 is [not backwards-compatible](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#overview-of-syntax-changes) with Python 2, so you do need to download and install Python 2.5 if you want to write compatible code.

Answer (score 3):

PyDev's grammar setting only changes the syntax highlighting. To know if your code *works* you must run it with Python 2.5, so yes you must download it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad idea to set the grammar to 2.5 from 3.1. Just download the older python 2.5 version and use the compiler and the libraries with it.  Between major versions changes happen to the API signatures and new features get added. You cannot afford to develop in high version in pydev and compile for another without encountering problem. Moreover Python 3.1 is backwards incompatible with Python 2.x (print is a function for e.g), so it is better you download and use Python 2.5 if that is the requirement.

Comment: It's more than just a bad idea.  It won't work.  Fixing syntax highlighting will be a waste of time.